# Incorrect Array usage in C++

Tags: c++, arrays

So I am supposed to make a function that takes an array and "Deletes" the even number and only spits out the odd numbers.  We have been given part of the code, which is the following:

```
int arr1[] = {1, 4, 7, 1, 2, 10, 1};
int size = sizeof(arr1) / sizeof(int);

keepOdd(arr1, size);

for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    cout << arr1[i] << " ";
cout << endl << "Totally " << size << " values left.";
```

I took that and expanded on it and I have come up with:

```
void keepOdd(int[], int);

void keepOdd(int& arr, int& size) {
int counter, newarr[size];
counter = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
   if (arr[i] % 2 == 1) {
      counter++;
      newarr[i]= arr[i];
      }
   }
size = counter;
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
   arr[i]=newarr[i];
}   




int main () {
int arr1[] = {1, 4, 7, 1, 2, 10, 1};
int size = sizeof(arr1) / sizeof(int);

keepOdd(arr1, size);

for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    std::cout << arr1[i] << " ";
std::cout << endl << "Totally " << size << " values left.";
}
```

But my code doesn't run at all.
Here is the error message:

```
extra credit.cpp: In function 'void keepOdd(int&, int&)':
extra credit.cpp:15:13: error: invalid types 'int[int]' for array subscript
    if (arr[i] % 2 == 1) {
             ^
extra credit.cpp:17:23: error: invalid types 'int[int]' for array subscript
       newarr[i]= arr[i];
                       ^
extra credit.cpp:22:9: error: invalid types 'int[int]' for array subscript
    arr[i]=newarr[i];
         ^
extra credit.cpp: In function 'int main()':
extra credit.cpp:36:14: error: 'endl' was not declared in this scope
 std::cout << endl << "Totally " << size << " values left.";
              ^~~~
extra credit.cpp:36:14: note: suggested alternative:
iostream:39:0,
                 from extra credit.cpp:1:
ostream:590:5: note:   'std::endl'
     endl(basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& __os)
     ^~~~
```

I have to use arrays but I don't see how I am supposed to properly use one.

Comment: `newarr[size];` - not valid C++ - array size must be a compile-time constant. Solution? don't use arrays, use std::vector.

Comment: Your code does not have valid syntax, so it would not compile. How do you expect it to run?

Comment: "Where did I go wrong?" Right from the beginning when you got the idea to re-implement `std::vector`

Comment: Scan array. When you find an even number move every item after the even number in the array back 1 slot to write over the even number. Keep a count of how many items are left in the array. You may find it a bit faster to start at the end of the array and work backward

Comment: Also, you don't need a second array at all.  What you are trying to do is *partition* the odd values from the even values.  So if you were to actually use C++, the solution is `size = std::distance(arr, std::partition(arr, arr + size, [](int n) { return n%2==1;}));`

Comment: What does "doesn't run at all" look like?  An error message?  Something else?

Comment: `extra credit.cpp:15:13: error: invalid types 'int[int]' for array subscript
    if (arr[i] % 2 == 1) {
             ^
extra credit.cpp:17:23: error: invalid types 'int[int]' for array subscript
       newarr[i]= arr[i];
                       ^
extra credit.cpp:22:9: error: invalid types 'int[int]' for array subscript
    arr[i]=newarr[i];
         ^
extra credit.cpp: In function 'int main()':
extra credit.cpp:32:19: error: no matching function for call to 'keepOdd(int [7], int&)'
 keepOdd(arr1, size);`
                   ^
@Drew

Comment: `newarray[count++]=array[i]` Typo !

Comment: @JohnnyMitchell that message is fundamental to your question.  You are asking what that message means.  Because being able to read and understand an error message is important.  Please [edit] your question.

Comment: Types used for calling the function are not correct ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
void keepOdd(int& arr, int& size) {
             ^^^^^^^^
```

The type of the first argument of your function with the name `arr` is "reference to an integer".

On this line within the function:

```
newarr[i]= arr[i];
           ^^^^^^
```

You apply the subscript operator on the referenced integer. There is no such operator where both the left hand side argument (`arr`) and right hand side argument (`i`) are integers. As such, the program is ill-formed. Hence the compiler error:

> ```
> error: invalid types 'int[int]' for array subscript newarr[i]= arr[i];
> ```

The same problem with the argument is cause for the other type-mismatch errors as well.

I suspect that you may have intended to use a pointer argument instead.

---

> ```
> error: 'endl' was not declared in this scope
> ```

You have used the indentifier `endl` in your program. There is no declaration for `endl` in your program. That is what the compiler is telling you.

The compiler also has found a potential solution for you:

> ```
> note: suggested alternative:
> iostream:39:0
> note:   'std::endl'
> ```

What the compiler is telling you, is that there is `std::endl` declared in the header `<iostream>`. `<iostream>` is a standard library header. If you indeed intended to use `std::endl` (and I suspect that you did), then you can use it by typing `std::endl` instead of `endl`.

P.S you probably don't need to use `std::endl`. `'\n'` is probably sufficient for you and won't unnecessarily slow the program down by flushing the output stream.

---

> ```
> int counter, newarr[size];
> ```

`size` is not compile time constant. The length of an automatic array must be compile time constant. Hence, the program is ill-formed.

If you need an array whose length is determined at runtime, you can allocate the array dynamically. The simplest way to allocate an array dynamically is to use `std::vector`.

Answer (score 1):

There are some changes needed to make your code work:

First, the function header for passing an array and size is something like this:

```
int keepOdd(int* arr, int size);
```

note that we will return an int: this is the new size of the array.

The logic of keepOdd can, then, be greatly simplified:

```
int keepOdd(int* arr, int size) {
    int counter;
    counter = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        if (arr[i] % 2 == 1) {
             arr[counter++]= arr[i];
         }
    }
    return counter;
}
```

Here you don't need to create a new array: you are rewriting even elements with the next odd element and returning the new array size.

Then, just use the new size to print the elements:

```
int main () {
    int arr1[] = {1, 4, 7, 1, 2, 10, 1};
    int size = sizeof(arr1) / sizeof(arr1[0]);
    std::cout << "size is " << size << "\n";

    int newSize = keepOdd(arr1, size);

    for (int i = 0; i < newSize; i++)
        std::cout << arr1[i] << " ";
    std::cout << std::endl << "Totally " << size << " values left.";
}
```